# For Multiple Tabs Single Fragment not working getItem called twice

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-tabs

Sir, I have to use **single fragment for multiple tabs**. I have implemented it using **FragmentStatePagerAdapter** but after debugging I have got that some of the tabs displays data but not correct. This is because **getItem called twice** please help me as early as possible.

I have passed arguments from getItem. it passes arguments two times as getItem calls twice. thus it overrides data of arguments. I have 6 tabs but only 1, 3 and 5 tab displays data but data is of 2, 4 and 6th tab and 2, 4 and 6th tab not showing anything on the screen.

not working any solution from previous questions.

ViewPager Code

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

int TAB_COUNT=5;
Context mContext;
public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm,Context context) {
    super(fm);
    mContext=context;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    NewsFragment fragment = new NewsFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("title", String.valueOf(getPageTitle(position)));
    args.putString("data", "data");
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;

}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

    return  mContext.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.tabs)[position];
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return TAB_COUNT;
}
```

}

Listeners to change tab :

```
@Override
public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

}



@Override
public void onPageSelected(int position) {

    TabLayout.Tab tab = tabLayout.getTabAt(position);
    if (tab != null) {
        tab.select();
    }
}
```

Adapter setting

```
 private void setUpTab() {
    viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), this);
    for (int i = 0; i < viewPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        tabLayout.addTab(
                tabLayout.newTab()
                        .setText(viewPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i)));
    }
    tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
    viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(this);
    tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(this);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

getItem gets called every time the adapter creates a new page for the first time. The reason you see it being called twice is that the viewPager prepares the next page in advance, so if you enter page 1, page 2 is already being created too for faster paging when you swipe right.

To help you further please show us the code for NewsFragment.

Also, you might consider using [FragmentPagerAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html) instead of FragmentStatePagerAdapter because you seem to have a fixed number of tabs (5 in your example) and according to the documentation that is the use case for FragmentPagerAdapter.

Documentation from the page I linked above:

> This version of the pager is best for use when there are a handful of typically more static fragments to be paged through, such as a set of tabs.